# Generating Excel Sheet With Images

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to generate excel sheet with Java using Netbeans, I want the excel sheet contain images that I can add using JFileChooser by parsing it to bytes in array and putting it in column A, while column B is description for that image, but the code I made is putting only one image in column B while I want to list more than one in different rows and giving them description in column B.

main class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Drawing;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Picture;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;



public class ExcelWriter {

    static String imagePath;
    static String imageDesc;

    static int numOfData;

    private static String[] columns = { "DropBox Link", "Description"};
    private static List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();


        static JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
    InvalidFormatException {

        //taking user input using Scanner Library
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("How many data you need?");
        numOfData = in.nextInt();
//      numOfData = numOfData+1;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfData; i++) {

                    System.out.println("Choose the file");

                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
                    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println("You chose to open this directory: " +
                    chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    }

                    imagePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            System.out.println("Description for it?");

            imageDesc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input");

                    datas.add(new Data(imagePath, imageDesc));

        }

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("dropboxLinks");
                //FileInputStream obtains input bytes from the image file
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                //Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte[].
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                //Adds a picture to the workbook
                int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                //close the input stream
                inputStream.close();
                //Returns an object that handles instantiating concrete classes
                CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
                //Creates the top-level drawing patriarch.
                Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                //Create an anchor that is attached to the worksheet
                ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
                //create an anchor with upper left cell _and_ bottom right cell
                anchor.setCol1(1); //Column B
                anchor.setRow1(2); //Row 3
                anchor.setCol2(2); //Column C
                anchor.setRow2(3); //Row 4
                //Creates a picture
                Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

                //Reset the image to the original size
                //pict.resize(); //don't do that. Let the anchor resize the image!

                //Create the Cell B3
                //Cell cell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(1);

        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 14);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

        // Create a Row
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
                    cell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
                    cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }

        // Create Other rows and cells with datas data
        int rowNum = 1;

        for (Data datas : datas) {
                    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(datas.imagePath);
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(datas.imageDesc);
        }

        // Resize all columns to fit the content size
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }

        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("dropboxLinks.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
              }


    }
```

Data class:

```
    public String imagePath;
      public String imageDesc;

      public Data(String imagePath, String imageDesc) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.imageDesc = imageDesc;
      }

}
```

I want a header on first row, the code start from second row to put an image using JFileChooser in column A, in column B I want it to be a description for that image in column A using JOptionPane.showInputDialog().

Comment: So, what is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is I want the image to display in column A but it's displayed in column B, can't insert multiple image.

Answer (score 0):

You never do iteration for `images`, you do iteration only for `imagePath` and `imageDescription`.

In your code :

`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath())`

This is get the last input, so your excel only have 1 last picture.

Correct here for solved your issue :

```
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("dropboxLinks");

        int startRow = 1;
        for(int intR=0; intR<datas.size(); intR++) {
                //FileInputStream obtains input bytes from the image file
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(datas.get(intR).imagePath);
                //Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte[].
                byte[] bytes = org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                //Adds a picture to the workbook
                int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
                //close the input stream
                inputStream.close();
                //Returns an object that handles instantiating concrete classes
                CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
                //Creates the top-level drawing patriarch.
                Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                //Create an anchor that is attached to the worksheet
                ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
                //create an anchor with upper left cell _and_ bottom right cell
                anchor.setCol1(1); //Column B
                anchor.setRow1(startRow);
                anchor.setCol2(2); //Column C
                anchor.setRow2(3); //Row 4
                //Creates a picture
                Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
                startRow++;
        }
                //Reset the image to the original size
                //pict.resize(); //don't do that. Let the anchor resize the image!

                //Create the Cell B3
                //Cell cell = sheet.createRow(2).createCell(1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, that was extremely helpful for me, but the problem isn't completely solved, now it displays 2 images, even if the user wanted to display more, referring to the code above `System.out.println("How many data you need?");
        numOfData = in.nextInt();` so if the user wanted 6 number of data and he selected the 6 images only 2 of them will be displayed in sheet which is in row 2 and 3.